# Prove that concave+convex=affine in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I want to prove that if a function $f:S\subset\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$  is at the same time concave and convex, then the function is affine. That's it, there exist 
$a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $z\in S$, $f(z)=az+b$.

I now how to do it when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ as I showed below, but I am having difficulties on extending the proof to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To prove it in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ I did as follows:

$f$ is convex in $S$ if $\forall x,y\in S$ and $\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$:
 $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$

$f$ is concave in $S$ if and only if $-f$ is convex in $S$.
Let us note that saying that $-f$  is convex in $S$  is equivalent to say that:

$\forall x,y\in S$ e $\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$ $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$

Thus, as $f$ is both concave and convex we have that
$\forall x,y\in S$ e $\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$:

$ f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$

We now need to prove that $f(z)=az+b$.

To do so we'll take $z=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$. Note that $z\in[x,y]$ and that $\lambda=\dfrac{z-y}{x-y}$. Thus, we now have that $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=f(z)$
and that:
$$\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=\dfrac{yf(x)-xf(y)}{y-x}+\left( \dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right) z$$

Therfore:
$$f(z)=\dfrac{yf(x)-xf(y)}{y-x}+\left( \dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right) z$$
So by taking $a= \dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ and $b=\dfrac{yf(x)-xf(y)}{y-x}$ we have $f(z)=az+b$ , as we wanted to prove.

**My problem** is that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I can't assume that $z\in[x,y]$ as they are vectors and $a$ and $b$ wouldn't be in  $\mathbb{R}$ as their denominator would be a vector.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But saying that $x,y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ wouldn't imply that $a$ and $b$ don't belong to $\mathbb{R}$ but to $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead? And, besides, how can I say a vector is "between" two other vectors?

Comment: Consider the line in $R^{n}$ determined by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You mean that then z will fall in the line, right @BrianBorchers?